# C# standard class (enumeration?) for Top, Bottom, Left, Right

Tags: c#

Is there a standard c# class that defines a notional Left, Right, Top and Bottom?

Should I just use my own?

```
enum controlAlignment
{
    left = 1,
    top,
    right,
    bottom,
    none = 0
}
```

Comment: If you're looking for a WPF namespaced item, you could try the System.Windows.Controls.Dock enumeration. It does not have the Flags attribute, and it does not support a 'None' option. [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.dock.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.dock.aspx)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles or System.Windows.Forms.DockStyles could do the job.

Answer (score 21):

A quick search revealed that the following Framework Enumerations already have these members (some have other additional members) :

- AnchorStyles - System.Windows.Forms
- Border3DSide - System.Windows.Forms
- DockStyle - System.Windows.Forms
- Edges - System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles
- TabAlignment - System.Windows.Forms
- ToolStripStatusLabelBorderSides - System.Windows.Forms
- VerticalAlignment - System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles

Comment: It's worth nothing that this search could be done using the "object browser" in Visual Studio.

Comment: AnchorStyles is the only one to match precisely, all other either miss 'None' or add 'All'; didn't consider VisualStyles.. ToolStripStatusLabelBorderSides is the best if you also want 'all'. (Of course the one with the longest name. I'll roll my own then..)

Comment: wouldve been nice if  ArrowDirection was included in this list, as pointed out by @dave Cousineau.. +1 for near complete list

Answer (score 13):

A nice enum might also be:

System.Drawing.**ContentAlignment** (in System.Drawing.dll)

These are its members:

```
public enum ContentAlignment
{
    TopLeft = 1,
    TopCenter = 2,
    TopRight = 4,
    MiddleLeft = 16,
    MiddleCenter = 32,
    MiddleRight = 64,
    BottomLeft = 256,
    BottomCenter = 512,
    BottomRight = 1024,
}
```

Comment: Hurray, something that is not Forms!

Comment: @DirkBester How is this not WinForms ? Or how can one make the condition `If you are using WPF/Silverlight` for the use of `System.Drawing` ? I don't even dare to try **not** to use System.Drawing.* when I prog WinForms. _(but actually this was also the answer I was looking for, not to the same question though)_

Comment: @Bitterblue The accepted answer uses System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles. This uses System.Drawing.ContentAlignment. See, no winforms stuff imported into my wpf.

Comment: @Bitterblue & DirkBester:  You are right with your comments. System.Drawing.dll is part of any standard WinForms project, but not of a standard WPF/Silverlight project. Just copy and paste this enum to your WPF/Silverlight project.

Answer (score 4):

Not unless you could the anchor styles (which has more). I'd roll my own for this. In the standard winforms library there are **separate** `VerticalAlignment` and `HorizontalAlignment` that might be useful.

Comment: Having a none option in an enum is something I usually add, so anchor styles looks like it does the job nicely!

Answer (score 3):

I often use [System.Windows.Forms.ArrowDirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.arrowdirection.aspx) for this, since it doesn't imply any particular intent.

Answer (score 2):

Since there is no standard enum in .NET exactly matching your requirements, I suggest creating your own (as I have done):

```
[Flags]
private enum Borders
{
    None = 0,
    Left = 1,
    Top = 2,
    Right = 4,
    Bottom = 8,
    All = Left | Top | Right | Bottom,
}
```

You can then query the individual edges by calling the `HasFlag` method. I agree with @dbkk, reusing enums with similar values but a different meaning can be confusing for anyone reading the code.

Answer (score 1):

Read up on the [FlagAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Well, both `AnchorStyles` and `DockStyles` have additional values besides the four you need; `AnchorStyles` additionally has `FlagAttribute` turned on which won't necessarily make sense (What would Top Left mean? What about Left Right?)

Since I can't think of any built-in functions that could generically take advantage of the standard Anchor- and DockStyles data types in any meaningful way, writing your own enumeration seems like a much saner alternative to linking against `Windows.Forms` just for the sake of an enum.

Unless, of course, you're already inside Windows.Forms, and one of @Cerebrus's suggestions actually makes sense in your context.

Answer (score 1):

For WPF projects (rather than WinForms) there's [`System.Windows.Controls.Dock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.dock). It has nothing but `Left`, `Top`, `Right` and `Bottom`.